# Cassandra: If a field inside an UDT is set to null, does this create a tombstone in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, null, upsert, user-defined-types

Please look at the following example:

---

**Insert**

```
INSERT INTO my_keyspace.my_table (id, name, my_info) VALUES (
  3464546, 
  'Sumit', 
  { birthday : '1990-01-01', height : '6.2 feet', weight : '74 kg' }
);
```

**Second Insert**

```
INSERT INTO my_keyspace.my_table (id, name, my_info) VALUES (
  3464546, 
  'Sumit', 
  { birthday : '1990-01-01', height : '6.2 feet', weight : null }
);
```

*Consider "id" as the Primary Key.*

---

In the second insert "weight" attribute inside "my_info" UDT is set as null. Does this create a tombstone? How null inside an UDT is stored in the Cassandra database?

Comment: is the UDT frozen or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Setting a column to NULL is the same as writing a tombstone in some cases.